# TypeId not printing information as expected

Tags: c++, typeid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Printing derived class name in base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894683/printing-derived-class-name-in-base-class)

I am using GCC, and the following code output something unexpected

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

class B {
  public:
  B ( B * ptr) { cout<< typeid(*ptr).name()<<endl;}
};

class  D : public B {
  public:
  D() : B(this) { cout<<typeid(this).name()<<endl;}
};

int main()
{
    D d;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
1B
P1D
```

Can anyone please explain to me why here the base class cannot tell the type of the derived class correctly?
Many thanks

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10894683/1025391

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two reasons:

1. The object (`*ptr`) hasn't been fully constructed yet.
2. Your classes are not polymorphic (no virtual member functions), so no dynamic type information exists.

Comment: But isn't typeid information known at compile time? If it is known at compile time then at runtime the derived class name should be printed.

Comment: @lorex: The dynamic type of `*ptr` is not known at compile-time.  And it's not completely constructed yet.

Answer (score 0):

that thing really depends on compiler. msvc provides different typeid string for that.